# How to change Flutter app ICON depending on flavor?

Tags: flutter

I want to create different apps flavor on the same base code for production, with the purpose of white labeling.

I need each flavor to have a different icon/splash screen/name.

I was already able to change the app name according to [How to change Flutter app name depending on flavor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497574/how-to-change-flutter-app-name-depending-on-flavor)

But how do I change the icon (and splash) depending on flavor?

The question is both for android and ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer specific to android icon:

using https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons#flavor-support

follow the instruction on this page,
but when you run `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f <your config file name here>` it will override your main `res` folder.

So before running this command, make a copy of this folder, then run the command, then copy `res` folder into a `android\app\src\<flavor_name>` and restore the original res folder.

NOTE that for android splash it will also use `android\app\src\<flavor_name>` so you can customise the splash this way as well

Answer (score 4):

For Android, you should use
[Flutter Launcher Icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons), using their flavors support.

For iOS, create a {your_flavor_name}.xcconfig file for each flavor, inside *ios/Flutter* and add to each of them:

```
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
FLUTTER_TARGET=lib/{your_flavor_main.dart_path}
// bundle_suffix used in the bundle id of the app
bundle_suffix=.{your_flavor_bundle}
// the name displayed below the app icon on the home screen
app_display_name={your_app_name}
//FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE=debug
```

Then, create a image file for each app icon inside Runner/Assets with the name AppIcon${your_flavor_bundle}.

Lastly, in XCode navigate to **Runner Target -> Build Settings-> Asset Catalog Compiler -> Primary App Icon Set Name**.
Now add to its value the following name (literally): **AppIcon$(bundle_suffix)**